# contact form 7 plugin shorcode in post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have put contact form 7 shorcode in post content have shortcode of contact form and displaying it on theme by following code:

```
  <?php $post_id = 157;
  $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
  echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
```

but it display same shortcode not the contact form. I am using Booklet theme.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do this in a round about way.  If you are trying to get just the form to render by placing the shortcode in the editor for a page, and then call that page's content in a template file there's a much cleaner built in function to accomplish this.  You don't need to grab the content from another page just to display your form.

Place this in your template file where you want the form to render:

`<?php echo do_shortcode([your_shortcode_here]) ?>`

Don't forget to put your shortcode where it says "your_shortcode_here".

If you really need to pull in the content from another page then you can do so with the following code:

```
<?php
    $page_id = 157;
    $page_data = get_page($page_id);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title; // Get title
    echo $content; // Output Content
?>
```

Just make sure the page ID matches the page you're wanting to get content from.